# CSS rotate and translate transform give unexpected results

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-animations

I've checked CSS-TRICKS and any other site Google offered me up to page two of their list of links, so my only assumption is I'm misunderstanding how this works or doing it wrong.

What I want is for an image to slide in from its current position to the absolute center of the page. As it slides, I want it to rotate at its center, spinning like a perfectly-balanced wheel. As it slides and rotates, I want it to appear to come towards the user. I want to do this while still keeping the image flat and unskewed.

What it does *instead* is rotate the image clockwise around and down back towards the left side of the page and off of it.

Here's my code (borrowed from animate.css and changed to suit my needs):

```
    @-webkit-keyframes rotOutZm {
    0% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 90deg) scale3d(3, 3, 3) translate3d(100% ,100% ,0);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 90deg) scale3d(3, 3, 3) translate3d(100% ,100% ,0);
    opacity: 0;
    }
    }

    @keyframes rotOutZm {
    0% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform-origin: center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 90deg) scale3d(3, 3, 3) translate3d(100% ,100% ,0);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 90deg) scale3d(3, 3, 3) translate3d(100% ,100% ,0);
    opacity: 0;
    }
    }

    .rotOutZm {
    -webkit-animation-name: rotOutZm;
    animation-name: rotOutZm;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
```

Currently, my code does *not* take into account the starting point of the image, which will be wrong/messy when I have a row of images. Is there a way to dynamically figure from their starting locations, if they need to slide up to the center, slide down to the center, etc? I'm pretty sure this is a job for JavaScript or jQuery but I'm not sure how to code that.

Am I simply expecting too much of the animation functions? Should I simplify my design to not do this due to complexity?

EDIT: Here is a JSFiddle showing the code in action. It's an image with a small delay to the animation so you can see the image and then watch how it animates to see my problem. My apologies for not providing this sooner.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hideto/jtLh00gj/)

Comment: Please supply a fiddle or pen of your code, including HTML.

Comment: I've added the requested code in a fiddle and updated the post to reflect that. Sorry for not including it sooner! I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do it:

[FireFox Live example](http://jsbin.com/zoyepu/2/edit)

```
@keyframes rotOutZm {
  100% {
    margin: -50px; /* image is 100x100px size so... */
    transform: translate3d(50vw, 50vh, 0) scale(3) rotate(360deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.rotOutZm {
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: rotOutZm 2s forwards 0.5s;
}
```

<sup>P.S: Expand the above also for `-webkit-` and other vendor prefixes</sup>

`vw` and `vh` are the *Viewport* sizes. `50vh` is half the viewport height

Note that is extremly important the order you place your stack of `transform`, i.e: if you move translate3d to the end or the transform rule you might get unwanted results.

Comment: I notice a problem when I stack two "ninjas" side-by-side. My ninjas are clickable. You click and they twirl and fade as you helped me accomplish. When I click on ninja1 and it twirls and fades correctly towards the user, ninja2 slides over to sit where ninja1 had just been. As well, ninja1 doesn't stay "gone". It pops right back to where it was, pushing ninja2 back to where it was supposed to stay. Any idea what's going wrong here? I have edited my above fiddle to include my code plus your code, and making the two ninjas clickable.

Comment: I'm not sure why the ninjas aren't twirling when clicked, however. They work on my test page, though. Here's the test [HTML](http://www.cafenocturne.com/testpage/biogallery/index.html) and [CSS](http://www.cafenocturne.com/testpage/biogallery/_styles.css).